# 'User Warning: Your Generator Is Empty' Fast.ai

Tags: generator, fast-ai, imagenet

Working on a project using fast.ai and ImageNet. I am using Google Colab, and have a folder of images. The goal is to determine which images contain rubber plants. The folder has 8 images, and I am trying to see how well the model will work with a small number of images. I am having trouble though because my code is saying my generator is empty. Any help would be great! I attached an image of my code and the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akLfE.png)

Comment: Please insert code/errors into your question instead of links to screenshots (except for image output when relevant): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2):

The dataset you have is too small (too few images), maybe add more training images or use smaller batch size.